# giving user defined data types to RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have an input file which is like this

A,1

B,2

C,3

```
val data = sc.textFile("myfile.txt")
```

How can i make this RDD to be in this format
data: RDD[(String, Int)]

I tried this but didnt work

```
case class foo (a: String, b: Int)
val data = sc.textFile("myfile.txt").map(
 c => foo(c(0).toString, c(1).toInt))
```

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried! Don't post it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an `rdd` of type `RDD[(String,Int)]` you should map your input to `Tuple2[String, Int]` instead of `foo`. Like this

```
 val data = sc.textFile("myfile.txt")
              .map(line => line.split(","))
              .map(s => (s(0), s(1).toInt))
```

(I added a `map` for splitting your data by `","`, which I think you probably forgot to add to your example).

Answer (score 0):

I think the most readable form would be:

```
sc.textFile("myfile.txt")
  .map { line =>
    val Array(first, second) = line.split(",")
    Foo(first, second.toInt)
  }
```

This doesn't handle errors though, both `Array(...)` and `toInt` can fail.

Comment: @Glennie Helles Sindholt my bad i forgot the split. I wanted to ask,if we didnt split on " ," and then we map (s => (s(0), s(1).toInt)) then it would just take the s(0) would be the first char on the file and the s(1) would be the second(the commas in our example) ?

Comment: in what way this doesnt handle errors? can you give me an example ? thank you both for your replies.

Comment: `toInt` will throw an exception if the String cannot be parsed to a number. The job would fail then.